# Invalid Type in query

Tags: multi-select

I am attempting to create the select list of options for a multi-select picklist by using a VisualForce page and a controller.

The scenario is this : I have an object for Vendors(Vendor_Profile__c). It has a child object of Products(Product_Profile__c). I have a separate object called Policy(Policy_Profile__c). When I create a new Policy I would like to choose which products are affected by the new Policy. The user would choose a Vendor it is relevant to in a lookup field (Vendor__c) and then I want a query to produce the select options of a multi-select picklist (Products_Affected2__c) with all of the Products available from that Vendor.

Currently, my controller is producing an 'Invalid type : Products_Affected2__c' (the multi-value field). This is the controller :

```
public class MycontrollerSFDC
{
    String policyid;
    public Policy_Profile__c policy{get;set;}
    public string relatedVendor{get;set;}
    public List<String> names{get;set;} // As multi select, that's why changes from string to list
    public string vendorid{get;set;}
    public string selectedvendorid{get;set;}
    public Name policynew{get;set;}

    public SelectOption[] SelectedProducts { get; set; }

    public MycontrollerSFDC(apexpages.standardcontroller controller)
    {
        policy = new Policy_Profile__c();
        policyid=system.currentpagereference().getparameters().get('id');

        if(policyid!=null)
        {
            policy=[select Vendor__c,Products_Affected2__c from Policy_Profile__c  where id =:policyid];
            relatedVendor=Policy.Vendor__c;
        }
    }

    public pageReference execute()
    {
        vendorid=policy.Vendor__c;
        System.debug('########'+vendorid);
        return null;
    }

    public list<selectoption> getitems()
    {
        List<selectoption> options= new list<selectoption>();
        SelectedProducts = new List<SelectOption>();
        if(vendorid != null)
        {
            Vendor_Profile__c a =[select name, ( Select Id, Name from Vendor_Products__r) from Vendor_Profile__c where id =:vendorid]; //Query the Policy Profiles
            for(Vendor_Product__c s : a.Vendor_Products__r)
            {
                options.add(new SelectOption(s.Id,s.name)); //Added the Id
            }
        }
        else
            options.add(new SelectOption('','None'));

        return options;
    }

    public void save()
    {
        System.debug('********************************' + names);

        // Added for multi select
        String products = '';

        for( String str : names )
        {
            products += products + ';';
        }

        products = products.subString( 0, products.length() - 1 );
        policy.Products_Affected2__c=products;
        // Added for multi select
        insert policy;

        policy=new Policy_Profile__c  ();
        System.debug('********************************' + policy);
    }
}
```

Here is the Visual Force page :

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Policy_Profile__c" extensions="MycontrollerSFDC">
    <apex:sectionheader title="New Policy"/>
<apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock mode="edit" title="{!$ObjectType.Policy_Profile__c.label} Edit">

            <apex:pageblockbuttons >           
                <apex:commandbutton value="Save New Policy" action="{!Save}"/>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
             </apex:pageblockbuttons>

     <apex:outputpanel id="ProductsDetails">
          <apex:pageblocksection title="Vendors  and Products" columns="2">
               <apex:inputfield value="{!policy.Vendor__c}" required="false" >
               <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!execute}"             
rerender="ProductsDetails,SelectedProducts" immediate="false" /> 
              </apex:inputfield>
<apex:inputfield value="{!policy.Products_Affected2__c}" required="false"/>
    </apex:inputfield>
          </apex:pageblocksection>

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Subsidiaries" id="SelectedProducts">

      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  
        <apex:outputLabel >Press Ctrl to select multiple subs:</apex:outputLabel>  
            <apex:selectList value="{!names}" multiselect="true" size="6">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!execute}"             
reRender="field"/>
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                </apex:selectList> 
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 

     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  
        <apex:outputLabel >Products Selected:</apex:outputLabel> 
        <apex:outputtext value="{!names}" id="field"/> 
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
     </apex:pageBlockSection>
       </apex:outputpanel>

        </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Could I please get some input on this problem ? There may be other problems with the code as well. I don't know because I have never been able to save and run it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if `Products_Affected2__c` is a multiselect picklist (MSP), then values assigned to it must be separated with semi-colons (`save()` method)

Comment: crop - I have a save( ) method in there. Am I using it incorrectly ?

Comment: what is `names` bound to in the VF page?

Comment: It is linked to the items selected. I've added the VF page now.

Comment: cool - use String.join to assemble a list of strings separated by a delimiter semi-colon - one statement

Comment: I've gotten it to work (for the most part). I've put the working code up on the original post. 
Thanks for all your help crop.

Answer (score 2):

First:

You are not querying for the Related Policy_Profiles__r in the vendor query

```
Vendor__c a =[select name from Vendor__c where id =:vendorid]
```

thus this will never run

```
for(Products_Affected2__c s : a.Policy_Profiles__r)
```

Maybe the query should be

```
Vendor__c a =[select name, (Select Products_Affected2__c From Policy_Profiles__r) from Vendor__c where id =:vendorid]
```

in addition the for above is invalid because Products_Affected2__c is a field on Policy_Profiles so it should be

```
for(Policy_Profile__c s : a.Policy_Profiles__r)
```

Comment: Eric - thank you very much for your help. 

I don't understand what you mean with "You are not queryingn for the Related Policy_Profiles__r in the vendor query". 

What do you mean by that ? Do you know what the proper query would be in that case ? Keep in mind, I have a Vendor__c field in the Policy_Profile object as well as a Vendor__c object. I don't know if that has anything to do with what you're saying, but I just wanted to mention that.

Comment: The way you were doing it makes it seem like the Policy_Profiles__r should be a subQuery in the vendor query you were doing via relationships. If it is just a field then why would you need a loop?

Comment: I changed the query by putting in the Product_Profile__c object. 

I'm trying to figure out a way to find the vendor from the Vendor__c field of the Policy_Profile__c object - and then somehow capture the name of all of the Product_Profile__c child records listed below it. 

But I'm at a loss for now.

Comment: Ok, I've got it working now. I put the correct code up on the original post. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @Zoom_v - Great, please mark as accepted if this answer helped solve it for you so that it does not keep surfacing.